# Preventdefault() en react no funciona

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios

Buenos días mi problema es simple, tengo un formulario para poder enviar los datos a un api, la cosa es que en el formulario tengo declarado que cuando haga submit en vez de enviar el formulario entre a un función pero al parecer no funciona y hace el submit igual aunque tengo `e.preventDefault();` y no se porque, probablemente es algo simple pero aun así no logro averiguarlo, les dejo el código del componente (borre unas partes para que no fuera tan largo)

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('xd');
    };

    render() {
        const formItemLayout = { labelCol:   { xs: { span: 24 }, sm: { span: 8  }}, wrapperCol: { xs: { span: 24 }, sm: { span: 16 }}};
        return (
            <Form {...formItemLayout} initialValues={{ remember: true }} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Item label="Email" name="email" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your email'}]}>
                    <Input onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item label="Password" name="password" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your password!' }]}>
                    <Input.Password onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name="remember" valuePropName="checked">
                    <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType='submit'> Submit </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Al hacerle click al boton deberia escribir en la consola un `xd` pero no lo hace y termina en enviando el formulario, estoy usando ant-desing no se si es de importancia pero lo aclaro igual, gracias de antemano

Comment: yo no he trabajado con ant design pero por lo que veo tienes que usar el la prop `onFinish={this.handleSubmit}`  que te devolverá los valores del form y hará el prevent default no hace falta que lo hagas tu. https://ant.design/components/form/#API

Comment: @hawks era exactamente eso, ya lo cambie y funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias <3

Comment: @hawks, sería bueno que lo publiques como respuesta, seguramente habrá otros usuarios con el mismo problema y con esto lo pueden resolver.

Comment: hecho @Triby. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas usar la prop `onFinish={this.handleSubmit}` que te devolverá los valores del `form`. El `onFinish` ya hace el `preventDefault` y te devuelve los valores de los inputs del form.

https://ant.design/components/form/#API